# JavaScript Splitting string not working

Tags: javascript, split

I am trying to split a string up but am having a problem in doing it.

My string is:

```
var EventList = "0x0,0x1,0x1 | 0x0,0xff,0x2 | 0x0,0x1,0x1 | 0x0,0x1,0x1 | 0x0,0xff,0x5 | 0x0,0xff,0x7 | 0x0,0xff,0x3 | 0x0,0xff,0x6";
```

I need to be able to Remove all spaces from the string (I am using the following code)

```
EventList = EventList.replace(/\s/g,'');
```

I them need to replace all | with , (comma) (I am using the following code)

```
EventList = EventList.replace('|',',');
```

I then need to split the string up by using the , (comma) (I am using the following code)

```
EventList = EventList.split(',');
```

I am trying to alart 0x2 from my string (I am using the following code)

alert(EventList[5]);

However, it is alerting 0x2|0x0 as the string and not 0x2.

My full code looks like this:

```
var EventList = "0x0,0x1,0x1 | 0x0,0xff,0x2 | 0x0,0x1,0x1 | 0x0,0x1,0x1 | 0x0,0xff,0x5 | 0x0,0xff,0x7 | 0x0,0xff,0x3 | 0x0,0xff,0x6";
EventList = EventList.replace(/\s/g,''); // replace any spaces in EventList
EventList = EventList.replace('|',',');  // replace any | with ,
EventList = EventList.split(',');       // Split EventList

alert(EventList[5]); // should alert 0x2 but it alerts 0x2|0x0
```

Anyone know where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `EventList.replace(/ /g, '')`?

Comment: @Jared Farrish - Yes that didn't work. It left the space there but if I used my way of removing the space it works

Comment: I don't get it: why use a regex to replace a space? Are you expecting other forms of whitespace?

Comment: @arxanas - I think most of it has to do with the number, otherwise it will only replace just the first instance. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: `(" " + " " + " ").replace(" ", "");` does in fact return `""`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a string as the first argument of `.replace()`, it will only convert the first ocurrence.

```
var EventList = "a|b|c|d";
EventList = EventList.replace('|',',');
alert("a,b|c|d"); // displays "a,b|c|d"
```

You need to use a regular expression with the `/g` global flag, like you did in the first place.

```
EventList = EventList.replace(/\|/g,',');  // replace any | with ,
```

(`|` needs to be escaped with a `\` backslash in the regular expression because it has a special meaning in regular expression syntax.)

I made this replacement and it displayed "0x2" as you said it should.

Comment: Thanks.. This did the job. Knew it would be something simple, just couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a global replace of the pipe bar /|/g.  I believe I have encounter this in the past - by default replace in not global in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Small mistake in your second replace. Should use a regex to replace "|". See below:

```
var EventList = "0x0,0x1,0x1 | 0x0,0xff,0x2 | 0x0,0x1,0x1 | 0x0,0x1,0x1 | 0x0,0xff,0x5 | 0x0,0xff,0x7 | 0x0,0xff,0x3 | 0x0,0xff,0x6";
EventList = EventList.replace(/\s/g,''); // replace any spaces in EventList
EventList = EventList.replace(/\|/g,',');  // replace any | with ,
EventList = EventList.split(',');       // Split EventList

alert(EventList[5]); // alerts 0x2
```